# Hibernate @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm using unidirectional @ManyToOne mapping. The code looks like this.

```
public class PolicyCatalogEntity  extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "policyReferenceId", referencedColumnName = "policyReferenceId",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PolicyConfigDetailsEntity policyConfigDetailsEntity;
    @NotBlank
    private String lobName;
 }
```

PolicyDetailsEntity looks like this

```
public class PolicyConfigDetailsEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    private Long policyReferenceId;
    @NotBlank
    private String policyName;
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

Do I need to specifically add column `policyReferenceId` in `PolicyCatalogEntity`?

PS: `policyReferenceId` is not the primaryKey. It's just a composite key.

If not then I'm getting following error
`Field 'policy_reference_id' doesn't have a default value`

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        policy_catalog
        (created_at, created_by, last_modified_by, updated_at, version, end_date, is_active, lob_name, lob_ref_id_type, start_date, tnc_url) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: If not then I'm getting following error 
`Field 'policy_reference_id' doesn't have a default value`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `insertable = false`
here:

@JoinColumn(name = "policyReferenceId", referencedColumnName = "policyReferenceId",
nullable = false, **insertable = false**, updatable = false)

hibernate will let your db handle the inserted value itself.
In that case you have to set a default value for that column in your db table design

also pay attention for `updatable = false`, which will only let you insert new values for that columns